# What's the best proxy for a stock contribution to the portfolio returns?

Tags: returns, performance-evaluation

I have a table of the weights of stocks in my portfolio for various periods and another with the returns that those stocks had for the same periods.

If I sum the product between the weights and the returns and compound the returns for each period, I will end up with my portfolio return for all periods.

I want to **calculate the contribution of each individual stock for my portfolio return across all periods**, in a manner that the result will sum to my total return.

Can you help me with this calculation?

Comment: Same question as [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65764/54838) I think. You cannot sim the individual contributions across periods because the weights change constantly.

Comment: I believe my case to be different because I know the weights for all periods. The portfolio's weights change at the end of each period. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Yes and that is why you cannot sum up the contributions of portfolio components to the total return of the portfolio (edit 2 in the link).

Comment: The method described by Feibel and mentioned here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36520/how-to-calculate-the-annual-contribution-of-a-fund-to-a-portfolio-of-funds/36530#36530 may help.